# Installing 2x16GB + 2x8GB ram in Dell R410?

Tags: memory, hardware, dell

In Dell's [memory guide](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-r410_User%27s%20Guide8_en-us.pdf) for the R410, they only give examples when using 16GB modules.

So my question is, how do I install 2x16GB + 2x8GB modules when having 2 CPU's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R410 is a old server. Size must match in the bank. (tri-channel and dual bank), (but slot 4 is a single slot bank)

Bank A1 & A2 = 2 x 16G
Bank B1 & B2 = 2 x 8G

or

Slot A4 = 1 x 16G
Slot B4 = 1 x 16G

You will got a "Unsupported memory configuration. DIMM mismatch across slots detected" if the memory does not fit across slot 1 to 3.

If you use slot #4, you will get a "Not optimal" warning, and thus ask a F1 to start.